# Devise sign_in method throws NoMethodError in RSpec test

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, nomethoderror

The Devise sign_in method is supposed to accept `store: false` as a second parameter, which it seems to do that fine unless I'm in `RSpec` and using the `Devise::TestHelpers`.

When I run this test from `sessions_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe Api::V1::SessionsController do
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  end
  ...
  describe 'DELETE #destroy' do
    before(:each) do
      sign_in @user, store: false
      delete :destroy, id: @user.auth_token
    end
    it { should respond_with 204 }
  end
end
```

I get this failure:
[image]

Comment: did you work this one out? I have the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not. But I will definitely post an answer if I find it. If you happen to run across a solution, could you do the same? I plan to get back to this project eventually, but finishing up grad school (last semester) first. Thanks for chiming in

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem. According to Devise website, there is no such method.
Try to remove the "store: false" parameter and run it again. It solved my problem.

```
...
describe 'DELETE #destroy' do
before(:each) do
  sign_in @user
  delete :destroy, id: @user.auth_token
end
it { should respond_with 204 }
...
```

And remember to put the following inside a file named spec/support/devise.rb or in your spec/spec_helper.rb (or spec/rails_helper.rb if you are using rspec-rails

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller 
end
```

[Take a look on this link](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/test-helpers)